# Cannot set p vertically

Tags: html, css

I want display the text on a new line for every p tag, so I did:

```
<div class="create-holiday">
  <p class="create-holiday-title">Create your holiday activity</p>
  <p class="create-holiday-subtitle">Hi! What are your holiday interests?</p>
</div>

.create-holiday *
{
    margin-top: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.create-holiday-title
{
  width: 297px;
  height: 22px;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.create-holiday-subtitle
{
  width: 276px;
  height: 18px;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

but the p tag are displayed on the same line.. What I did wrong?

Comment: add <br> tag between your <p> tags. Or make 100% width

Comment: I am able to see those two are on separate lines. If possible please provide fiddle link

Comment: you are seeking for the default behavior ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your p tag's widths are set to less than 100% and/or your p tags are set to a display of inline or inline-block.

In your CSS file, try this:

```
p {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If that doesn't work, you can always add br tags at the end of each p tag, but you really shouldn't have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Add A br tag in the middle of the p tags so they don't show up on the same line

Comment: Add A? What does this even mean?

Comment: sorry messed it up

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` tags are block level elements, and therefore you don't need `<br>` tags. Your code seems to work for me...

```css
.create-holiday * {
    margin-top: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.create-holiday-title {
    width: 297px;
    height: 22px;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.create-holiday-subtitle {
    width: 276px;
    height: 18px;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class="create-holiday">
  <p class="create-holiday-title">Create your holiday activity</p>
  <p class="create-holiday-subtitle">Hi! What are your holiday interests?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree.  I do not see any problem with the `<p>` elements not behaving as blocks.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="create-holiday">
   <p class="create-holiday-title">Create your holiday activity</p>
   <p class="create-holiday-subtitle">Hi! What are your holiday interests?</p>
</div>

.create-holiday * {
   margin-top: 100px;
   display: flex; //make it flex
   align-items: center; //flex middle vertical align
   justify-content: center; //flex center align
}
.create-holiday-title {
   width: 297px;
   height: 22px;
   overflow: hidden; //force p to height and width size
   color: #333333;
   font-family: Montserrat;
   font-size: 22px;
   font-weight: 700;
}
.create-holiday-subtitle {
   width: 276px;
   height: 18px;
   overflow: hidden; //force p to height and width size
   color: #333333;
   font-family: Roboto;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: could you please explain your code, so the reader can understand your point?

Comment: We are not examine your english skills. Some information you provide us can be helpful. And of course someone can edit your post by removing grammar spellings